# rust says trait From<i32> isn't implimented

Tags: rust, traits

I've got an enum:

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
pub enum EventValue {
    Numeric(i32),
    Bool(bool),
    Text(String),
}
```

And it's used in a `Vec` which is used in a HashMap:

```rust
type Events = Vec<Event>;
pub type Stream = HashMap<String, Events>;
```

and I've implemented the `From` trait on it for `i32` (and the other three types):

```rust
impl From<i32> for EventValue {
    fn from(v: i32) -> Self {
        EventValue::Numeric(v)
    }
}

impl From<String> for EventValue {
    fn from(v: String) -> Self {
        EventValue::Text(v)
    }
}

impl From<bool> for EventValue {
    fn from(v: bool) -> Self {
        EventValue::Bool(v)
    }
}
```

but when I try to use it in a function:

```rust
let motions = event_stream.get_channel("motions"); // << return a Vec
for motion in motions.drain(0..) {
    let amount: i32 = motion.value.into(); // <-- here is where I get the error
    // .. do somthing with amount
}
```

I get this error:

```sh
the trait bound `i32: std::convert::From<prelude::game::entity::components::event_stream::EventValue>` is not satisfied
  --> src/game/system/entity/movement.rs:17:48
   |
17 |                 let amount: i32 = motion.value.into();
   |                                                ^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<prelude::game::entity::components::event_stream::EventValue>` is not implemented for `i32`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <i32 as std::convert::From<bool>>
             <i32 as std::convert::From<i16>>
             <i32 as std::convert::From<i8>>
             <i32 as std::convert::From<std::num::NonZeroI32>>
           and 2 others
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::Into<i32>` for `prelude::game::entity::components::event_stream::EventValue`
```

What have I missed?

Bonus:

It's possible to build a function that auto converts incoming values for you provided you implement `From` like this:

```rust
impl Event {
    pub fn new<V: Into<EventValue>>(message: String, value: V) -> Event {
        Self {
            message: message,
            value: value.into(),
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to create a function that can do the same thing but for returning a value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error says that `From<EventValue>` isn't implemented for `i32`, not that `From<i32>` isn't implemented for `EventValue`. With the fully qualified names, it's a little harder to read, but that's what

> the trait bound `i32: std::convert::From<prelude::game::entity::components::event_stream::EventValue>` is not satisfied

is saying.

The problem is that you're going the wrong direction. You've implemented the conversion `i32` -> `EventValue`, but not `EventValue` -> `i32`, which is what your sample code is trying to do.

You'll probably want to match on the value instead and handle not only the `Numeric` case, but also the `Bool` and `Text` cases.

```
let motions = event_stream.get_channel("motions"); // << return a Vec
for motion in motions.drain(0..) {
    match motion.value {
        Numeric(value) => {// handle `Numeric` case},
        Bool(value) => {// handle `Bool` case},
        Text(text) => {// handle `Text` case},
    }
}
```

`motion.value` could be any of those three variants, so you can't assume it'll always be convertible to `i32`.

Comment: @Thermatix If `motion` is truly always `Numeric`, you may want to consider using a different type. Alternatively, you can ignore any non-`Numeric` variants by replacing the match statement with `if let Numeric(value) = motion.value { //...}`. Finally, you could simply panic in the other cases if you're certain that all the events are always `Numeric`. The `unreachable!()` macro is appropriate here.

Comment: Thanks to your input, I Implemented `From<EventValue>` for `i32` so `EventValue` -> `i32`  and it worked, I simply match against the enum; if it's anything other then the expected value I panic as it should never be that value if it has then something has gone very wrong.